# Butterfly Theorem

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ an isosceles acute triangle and $D$ be the middle of the base $AB$.

Let's consider $E \in AB$ and $O$, the circumcenter of the triangle $ACE$.

Prove that the perpendicular in $D$ on $OD$, the perpendicular from $E$ to $BC$, and the parallel through $B$ at $AC$ are concurrent.

I tried to apply Butterfly Theorem from [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Butterfly.shtml).

[image]

Comment: It seems you had asked the same question before. Not sure ...

Comment: Why did you erase your November 22nd interesting question about the inscribed quedrilateral, to which I had added a figure ? Maybe you have a solution and I would be happy to know it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometric solution:I could not construct an isosceles triangle with this statement, it became an equilateral triangle. May be it is a particular case. Draw like: A is top vertex, clockwise marking B is right and C is left of the base.

Find the mirror of E about BC, mark it as F.Mark intersection of EF with BC as H. connect O to F. Draw a circle on diameter OF, clearly it passes point D. EF is perpendicular on BC, and:

$\triangle EHB=\triangle FHB\Rightarrow \angle CBE=\angle CBF$

But: $\angle CBE=\angle ACB\Rightarrow \angle ACB=\angle CBF$

This means that $BF||AC$.

Now we have to show B is on the circle with diameter OF. This is clear because BO is altitude of triangle ABC and is perpendicular on AC and thereby on BF, which means $\angle OBF = 90^o$ which in turn means B is on the circle with diameter OF.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how Butterfly Theorem should be applied here but there is an algebraic solution to this problem ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647902/synthetic-solution-for-proving-that-a-quadrilateral-constructed-on-the-altitude/4648028#4648028) is another solution to another problem with the same approach). WLOG, let's place your figure on the Cartesian coordinate system such that:
$$A=(-1,0),\\ B=(1,0), \\ C=(0,a), \\ E=(b,0), \\ D=(0,0).$$

First, we need to calculate the coordinates of $O$, which is the intersection of the lines $x=\frac{-1+b}{2}$ (perpendicular bisector of $AE$) and $y=\frac{-1}{a}x+\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}$ (perpendicular bisector of $AC$). So, we have:

$$O=(\frac{-1+b}{2}, \frac{a^2-b}{2a}).$$

[image]

Now, assume the perpendicular to $OD$ at $D$ and the perpendicular to $BC$ from $E$ intersect each other at $M$.
It is very easy to see that the equation of $DM$ is:

$$y=\frac{a-ab}{a^2-b}x,$$

and the equation of $EM$ is:

$$y=\frac{1}{a}x-\frac{b}{a}.$$

Thus,

$$M=(\frac{a^2-b}{a^2-1}, \frac{a-ab}{a^2-1}).$$

To prove the claim, we only need to show that the slope of the line passing through $M$ and $B$ is equal to the slope of the line $AC$, which is $a$.

To do so,

$$\frac{\frac{a-ab}{a^2-1}-0}{\frac{a^2-b}{a^2-1}-1}= \frac{a-ab}{a^2-b-a^2+1}=a.$$

We are done.